# Jquery dialog not working from accordion with ckedior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-dialog

I am using ckeditor in Jquery accordion, I have a button in every accordion after ckeditor.

On that save button's click, I am checking the content of ckeditor, if value is none, then I want to show jquery's dialog box with proper error message.

But It is giving me error

```
Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
```

My code to add ckeditor in accordion

```
   $("#question-container textarea").each(function(){
       CKEDITOR.replace(($(this).attr('id')), subjetive_config);
   });
```

My code to call dailog in case of error

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textarea_id];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }

    $("#dialog").html("Answer can not be empty!");
    $("#dialog").attr('title', 'Error');
    $("#dialog").dialog({draggable: false,resizable: false,modal: true,buttons: { "Close": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("destroy"); 
                        } 
                    } 
                });
}
```

Any pointer or suggestions would be great
Thanks

Comment: You have missed the braces, check the answer below.

Comment: Sorry, It was my editing mistake. I have edited the question. And I have included Jquery library and jquery ui library files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the **jQuery** library file.

In your code, you have missed the braces while initializing the dialog.
This will help you:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
             {
             text: "Close",
             click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "destroy" );
             }
             }
             ]
});
```

Also have a look at [Dialog Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close).